# How can I implement a video tag using WebView React-Native?

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I am trying to serve multiple local video files. I originally tried the module react-native-video, but after coming into many errors (yes, I've included the java code from the docs in `settings.gradle/build.gradle/MainApplications.java` etc) and seeing many similar unsolved issues on the internet. I would like to switch to an easier to use HTML5 video player.

Is there anyway to use HTML5 native video player with WebView? What would the syntax for this be? Will this still work when the device is offline as well?

Answer (score 0):

Videos can be successfully shown inside the WebView using  tags etc. It won't work for offline/local files.
Diving into react native requires some resilience and perseverance, nothing really works easily out-of-the-box but once you master the native module parts you should be good to go.